# Contents of the string after failed extraction from istream

Tags: c++, extract, istream

If I do this:

```
ifstream stream("somefilewhichopenssuccesfully.txt");
string token;
if( stream >> token )
    cout << token;
else
    cout << token;
```

Is the output in the second case guaranteed to be an empty string? I can't seem to find the answer to this on cplusplus.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the output in the second case guaranteed to be an empty string?

The answer is : no, because it depends, as described below.

Since `else` block will be executed only if an attempt to read from the stream fails, and that can occur anytime in the course of reading.

- If it fails at the very first attempt, then there is no character extraction from the stream, and hence `token` will  be empty (as it was).
- If it fails after few reads, then `token` will not be empty. It will contain the  characters successfully read so far from  the stream.

The section §21.3.7.9 from the Standard says,

> Begins by constructing a sentry object
>   k as if k were constructed by typename
>   basic_istream::sentry
>   k(is). If bool(k) is true, it calls
>   str.erase() and then **extracts
>   characters from is and appends them to
>   str as if by calling str.append(1,c)**.
>   If is.width() is greater than zero,
>   the maximum number n of characters
>   appended is is.width(); otherwise n is
>   str.max_size(). **Characters are
>   extracted and appended until any of
>   the following occurs**:
>
> — n characters
>   are stored;
>
> — end-of-file occurs on
>   the input sequence;
>
> — isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the
>   next available input character c.
>
> After the last character (if any) is
>   extracted, is.width(0) is called and
>   the sentry object k is destroyed.
>
> If the function extracts no characters, it calls is.setstate(ios::failbit), which may throw ios_base::failure (27.4.4.3).

---

Also note that the section §21.3.1/2 from the Standard guarantees that the default constructed string will be empty. The Standard says its size will be zero, that means, empty.

Comment: @Nawaz: I meant a guarantee that the `istream` won't alter the string if it doesn't succeed.

Comment: @Nawaz: The constructor isn't relevant, the operator clears the string anyway. The point is, what happens if a few characters have been read into the string and you then get failbit set by a read operation - what happens to the partially extracted string. This seems not to be explicit in the standard, it only mentions eof in this context.

Comment: @Nawaz: That still doesn't say what happens if it extracts 3 chars and *then* get a failure other than EOF.

Comment: @Erik: But whatever it says, it makes clear that `token` will not be empty if even a single read was successful as it reads and appends.

Comment: @Nawaz: That's what it looks like yes - so the answer to the OP would be "No".

Comment: Thanks all of you, I guess this is pretty definitive `:)`

Comment: @Erik: Yeah. I explicity said "No" now :P

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my original answer because I wanted to test this. This is what I see, if there is an error whilst reading (EOF is not counted in this context), the original string is modified and the branch sees the modified version. To test I did the following, created a 2Gb file (`touch` then `truncate`), the above code to read. Whilst the code was running, removed the file (this should set the `failbit` - I think). Immediately stops reading, but the string is modified - it has a larger size.

To me this indicates that the string is modified even if the stream operation fails.

Comment: @Nawaz, sorry your comment appears out of context, I deleted my original answer to test properly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this won't guarantee this behavior everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, even if the operation fails, the string will contain the characters extracted so far.

The standard says (§21.4.8.9):

> Effects: Behaves as a formatted input function (27.7.2.2.1). After constructing a `sentry` object, if the sentry converts to true, calls `str.erase()` and then extracts characters from `is` and appends them to `str` as if by calling `str.append(1,c)`. If `is.width()` is greater than zero, the maximum number n of characters appended is `is.width()`; otherwise n is `str.max_size()`. Characters are extracted and appended until any of the following occurs:
>    — n characters are stored;
>   — end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
>   — `isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next available input character c.